# Refreshing TR after TD is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlapping

I have a table tag having trs and tds. At runtime I am adding an image to one of the tds and simultaneously moving it to overlap the old data in the td. This shows the image overlay nicely but the size of the td once changed does not return back to appropriate. Now that the image has moved space is left below it in the td. I want to be able to redraw or refresh the tr to display the data properly.
I have tried changing the style attributes of the td so that the system is forced to do a refresh for the page. But no change. Please help me with this.

```
    imgstring = "<img src='Images/comment.JPG' width='60' height='42' alt='' title='' class='forImg' />";
var obj = document.getElementById("id for a td");
var leftCoord = $(obj).offset().left;
var topCoord = $(obj).offset().top;

$(imgstring).appendTo(obj).css({'visibility':'visible',
                'top':function(index,value){return value = -($(this).offset().top - topCoord) + "px";},
                 'left':function(index,value){return value = -($(this).offset().left - leftCoord) + "px";},
                 });
```

The above code sets the overlapping properly but the space remaining after the image is moved does not get removed.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Set a trigger on the td event and a listener on the tr event:

```
$(imgstring).appendTo(obj).css({'visibility':'visible',
                'top':function(index,value){return value = -($(this).offset().top - topCoord) + "px";},
                 'left':function(index,value){return value = -($(this).offset().left - leftCoord) + "px";},
                 }).trigger('td_updated');

$('tr').live('td_updated',function()
{
  // resize tr to match new height of td
});
```

Comment: could you please post the actual resizing code, since I have not given the hieght to the tr nor to the td will i be able to do something like get the td from the event object and retrieve its hieght and give it to the parent tr. This could be wrong in cases where the td is not the one having the most hieght.

Answer (score 0):

I'm keeping my other answer because I can see it being useful for another individual, but this is essentially what you need for your particular case:

CSS:

```
    td img {
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
```

Simple as that ;)

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/SQGwa/5/

The actual problem is being caused by the DOCTYPE and how it interprets linebreaks in your code.

This won't cause this issue:

```
<td><img src="whatever /></td>
```

This will:

```
<td>
    <img src="whatever" />
</td>
```

Looks like when jQuery appends the img node, it formats the code in such a way to cause this issue.

Comment: my table string is computed and hence there is no line break in the tag. I tried giving the style as mentioned above in my code mentioned in my question but no effect.

Comment: Did you click the jsfiddle link? Working example, sir. Remove the CSS to see your issue in full effect. Replace the CSS to see your issue resolved.

Comment: yes i went to the url. but could not see anything as the image is not visible.

Comment: Updated the link - added a remote image and a red border to it so you can clearly see what is happening.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. Saw the link. What I want to do is put the image over my text, which I have done in the code posted by me. By giving the vertical alignment in the style i push the image to the bottom of the td which is not what i want! If you try the jsfiddle with some data in both the td's you will see that the fist td data comes before the image. I want the image to overlap over the data. Once this is done the td expands to include the image but does not squeze back to the sufficient space later. This is my problem. For this I felt that refreshing the td /tr would be the solution.

Comment: Next time you should specify these requirements before people start troubleshooting your issue without all the details.

Comment: Does the image need to overlap the data or can it replace the data?

Comment: I have already mentioned the overlapping. Sorry if it wasnt clear. The image must overlap the data. This is done using the offset settings in the css as shown in my code. Only problem i cant figure out is the refreshing or redrawing of the table. It keeps its expanded size!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with page refresh. For the CSS 'top' and 'left' values to work, you must have CSS 'position' set to absolute, relative or fixed, but you don't show this. My guess is "relative", in which case, the space allocated for the image in its original position remains, even after the image itself has been shifted.

You may be able to remove this by setting a margin-right value on the img equal to minus the width of the image.

Comment: I have given the position as relative for the image. I guess this is the root of the empty space below the image after repositioning. But I cannot calculate the position in the td unless i have relative positioning. Is there a way out of this ??